# Скрытый блок при загрузке страницы JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Вчера еще все работало нормально, но сегодня почему-то не работает, без понятия почему и что этому способствовало. Проблема такова. Есть у меня блок слайдер. Он скрывается по нажатию кнопки, и в `local storage` добавляется значение `_slider=hide`, если он открыт, то значение `_slider=show` либо вообще отсутствует. Мне надо слелать так, чтобы, если он был ранее скрыт, то при загрузке страницы он всё так оставался скрытым. Сейчас проблема такова: страница загружается, он открытый, после полной загрузки он закрывается (съезжает вверх). Вчера все так и работало, но сегодня перестало.

**HTML**

```
<div class="sliderBlock">

        <p id="hideSlider"></p>

        <h2><input type="text" name="sliderH2" value=" текст "></h2>

        <h3><input type="text" name="sliderH3" value=" текст "></h3>

        <p><input type="text" name="sliderP1" value=" текст "></p>

        <p><input type="text" name="sliderP2" value=" текст "></p>

    </div><!-- .sliderBlock -->
```

**jQuery** 
Функция которая за это отвечает:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var sliderBlock = $('.sliderBlock');
    var hideSlider = $('#hideSlider');
    var storage = $.localStorage;

    if (storage.get('_slider') == 'hide') {
        sliderBlock.css({'height': '50px'});
        hideSlider.css({'transform': 'rotate(-45deg)'})
    }

    hideSlider.click(function () {
        if (storage.get('_slider') == 'show' || !storage.get('_slider')) {
            storage.set('_slider', 'hide');
            sliderBlock.css({'height': '50px'});
            hideSlider.css({'transform': 'rotate(-45deg)'})
        } else {
            storage.set('_slider', 'show');
            hideSlider.css({'transform': 'rotate(0)'});
            sliderBlock.css({'height': '350px'})
        }
    });

}); // Slider SHOW / HIDE functions
```

**CSS** и стили его, если надо:

```
.sliderBlock {
  width:            100%;
  height:           350px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  position:         relative;
  transition:       0.3s;
  overflow:         hidden;

  #hideSlider {
     position:            absolute;
     top:                 10px;
     right:               10px;
     background-color:    #191717;
     background-image:    url("../image/squareClose.png");
     background-repeat:   no-repeat;
     background-position: center center;
     width:               30px;
     height:              30px;
     display:             block;
     cursor:              pointer;
     transition:          .3s;
     z-index:             999;
     border-radius:       5px;

     &:hover {
        background-color: #2F2B2B;
        transition:       0.2s;
        cursor:           pointer;
        transform:        rotate(-45deg);
     }
  }

  h2 {
     position: absolute;
     top:      70px;
     left:     10%;
     cursor:   default;
     width:    895px;

     > input {
        font-size:        40px;
        color:            #2F2B2B;
        text-shadow:      0 0 5px;
        font-weight:      400;
        background-color: transparent;
        width:            100%;
        border:           none;
        display:          block;
        padding:          0px 0 0 15px;
        border-radius:    5px;
        transition:       .3s;
     }
  }

  h3 {
     position: absolute;
     width:    805px;
     top:      130px;
     left:     19%;
     cursor:   default;

     > input {
        font-size:        40px;
        color:            #2F2B2B;
        text-shadow:      0 0 5px;
        font-weight:      400;
        background-color: transparent;
        width:            100%;
        border:           none;
        display:          block;
        padding:          0px 0px 0 15px;
        border-radius:    5px;
        transition:       .3s;
     }

     span {
        font-weight: 800;
     }
  }

  p.sliderPar {
     width:    765px;
     position: absolute;
     top:      190px;
     left:     23%;
     cursor:   default;

     > input {
        font-size:        25px;
        color:            #2F2B2B;
        text-shadow:      0 0 5px;
        font-weight:      400;
        background-color: transparent;
        width:            100%;
        border:           none;
        display:          block;
        padding:          0px 0px 0 15px;
        border-radius:    5px;
        transition:       .3s;
     }
  }

  p.sliderPar2 {
     position: absolute;
     top:      229px;
     left:     15%;
     cursor:   default;
     width:    845px;

     > input {
        font-size:        25px;
        color:            #2F2B2B;
        text-shadow:      0 0 5px;
        font-weight:      400;
        background-color: transparent;
        width:            100%;
        border:           none;
        display:          block;
        padding:          0px 0px 0 15px;
        border-radius:    5px;
        transition:       .3s;
     }
  }

  p.saveBtn {
     position:      absolute;
     top:           290px;
     width:         140px;
     height:        38px;
     left:          5%;
     color:         #2F2B2B;
     overflow:      hidden;
     border-radius: 5px;
     box-shadow:    0 0 5px #191919;

     > input {
        display:          block;
        height:           38px;
        border:           none;
        width:            100%;
        background-color: #232927;
        color:            #ADADAD;
        padding:          10px 15px;
        cursor:           pointer;
        transition:       .3s;

        &:hover,
        &:active {
           transition:       .3s;
           background-color: #1B5D42;
        }
     }
  }
}
```